# Using Jquery to toggle HTML and CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm looking to use jquery for a sort of toggle button to toggle between the two below states;

[image: Toggle A]

[image: Toggle B]

So everything in picture A (above the red line) is hidden when i click the Toggle Button/link and when i click the toggle button again, it reappears.

I've been looking into Jquerys toggleClass function;

```
$("button").click(function(){
$("p").toggleClass("main");
});
```

But this i beleive would only hide the CSS, not the HTML too. Am i misusing the function or is not make for this?

thanks

Comment: I don't really get what you mean by "hide the CSS, not the HTML too" to be honest. It doesn't hide anything, it just adds or removes (depending on whether or not the matched elements already **had** the class) the class from the matched elements. If your CSS declaration for `.main` includes `display:none` then it will cause any elements matched, and given that class, to no longer be visible. The HTML and CSS still exists in the DOM, though.

Comment: i was using toggleclass which didnt hidethe HTML, just the CSS. As other's have answered using toggle or slidetoggle did the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/pV7Qe/

```
<div class="header">header</div>
<div class="menu">
    <div class="my-toggle">toggle</div>
</div>
<div class="content">
content            
</div>

.header
{
    background:lime;
}
.menu
{
    height:100px;
    background:gray;        
}
.my-toggle
{
    width:100px;
    background:red;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.content
{
    height:500px;            
    background:#ddd;
}​

$(".my-toggle").click(function() {
  $(".header").slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, chose your's as the sliding effect is a great addition. Really impressed with jquery so far.

Answer (score 2):

If you can put everything above the red line into a single containing element, with a unique ID, you can simply use the [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) jQuery function on that single element to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Consider two classes

```
.hide{visibility: hidden;}
.show{visibility: visible;}
```

Now use this JQuery Code

```
$("button").click(function(){
$("p").toggleClass('hide','show');
});
```

This would solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the toggle function.

```
$("idOfButton").click(function(){
    $(".main").toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the toggle function without any parameter..

```
   $("button").click(function(){
$("p").toggleClass();
});
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `slideToggle()`, `toggle()` or `toggleClass('hidden')`

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

References:

- [slideToggle](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/)
- [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)
- [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

Answer (score 0):

No reason to use toggleClass and have extra css for a hidden class.

Simply use toggle, or slideToggle for a better effect, which everyone here has suggested.

My only added input would be is that instead of

```
$('.buttons').click(function(){
    $('#div').slideToggle();
});
```

I believe it is better practice to use 'on'

```
$('.buttons').on('click', function(){
    $('#div').slideToggle();
});
```